# Outlook table spacing in HTML email - no usual tricks working

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have a button that in order for it to work in Outlook 2007/10 (!) I have to put the three elements - left image, middle text, right image - in their own nested tables within a larger table. However, this causes the oft-quoted issue in Outlook 2007/10 which has the gaps between the tables.

Below is the code for the button. Obviously, there's the `html` `head` `body`  etc above it.

I've tried display attributes, widths, align, border/padding/margin = 0 on img and tables alike... I've tried every solution I could find online and nothing is fixing it!

Any ideas for what else to try gratefully received!!

Note: this is happening across the board in Outlook, not just one of them.

```
<tr>
<td style="width: 15px; font-size: 15px;" valign="top">&#160;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="243" border="0" style="margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; display: block; background-color: #f2f2f2;" valign="middle">
<tbody valign="middle">
<tr height="40">
    <td height="40">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="22" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; width: 22px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #f2f2f2; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; display: block;" valign="middle">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="40" width="22" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank">
        <img align="right" height="40" src="ctaleftgrey.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px; display: block;" width="22" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="180" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; display: block; border-left: 1px solid #ec6608;" valign="middle">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: #ec6608;">
        <td height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff" target="_blank">Text goes here</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="36" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; width: 36px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #f2f2f2; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; display: block;" valign="middle">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="40" width="36" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img align="right" height="40" src="ctarightgrey.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px; display: block;" width="36" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="width: 15px; font-size: 15px;" valign="top">&#160;</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was surprisingly tough! I found that part of the issue was caused by the align="center" on the outer table, causing a 3px gap in Outlook 2003 and Live Mail. If you still need it to align to the center, I would wrap this code in another table with that attribute. To solve the rest of it I removed extra tables and added align to your TDs. I also added "border-collapse: collapse;" to your tables. You should see no spacing in desktop Outlook clients now.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="238" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:238px; color: #ffffff; width:238px;height: 40px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #f2f2f2;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="40" width="22" align="left">
                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                        <a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank">
                            <img height="40" src="ctaleftgrey.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" />
                        </a>
                    </p>
        </td>
        <td height="40" width="180" align="left">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" width="180" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; " valign="middle">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text goes here</a>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td height="40" width="36" align="left">
                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img height="40" src="ctarightgrey.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" />
                        </a>
                    </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff - I got excited because I thought that had cracked it! But it then causes a new alignment issue in other Outlooks (older ones like 2002) like this: http://postimg.org/image/bhwlka3yx/ I thought maybe a `display` attribute on the img/nested table might do it but made no impact - any ideas?

Comment: Threw some `valign`s onto the table cells: BOOM! Houston, we have alignment!!! @geoff-phillips , you are my new best friend and I love you! I have been battling with this for DAYS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `table-layout` in `<table>` tags. If this still not working, you need to change your table layout to a float / display layout.

```
 <table style="table-layout: fixed; [.....]">
```

The float layout is like this:

```
 <a href="..." style="float:left;"><img ....>
```

Comment: Hi Marcos - thanks, but I tried adding table-layout:fixed to no avail; floats are bad in emails and generally upset things

Comment: I am waiting for the day that Microsoft kills outlook and Internet Explorer, but we haven't lucky about this

Comment: Agreed... Or better - everyone on the planet just uses one email system that works with divs not tables! :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain! been making email templates and having these battles with Outlook for years now. The answer is that you need to do everything in your power to make the simplest little section work. I would make the background-color of each cell the orange, and align the left image to the left, and the right to the right https://jsfiddle.net/0gncaogm/.

I've also added classes (to accompany your inline widths) to make the cells a max-width with overflow-x:hidden...

```
img{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.leftedge{
    max-width:15px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.rightedge{
    max-width:36px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

In the HTML...

```
<td height="40" width="36" style="background-color: #e76823;" align="right>    
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img align="right" height="40" src="http://www.tonytansley.co.uk/so/right.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px; display: block;" width="36" />
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi Tony - Thanks but I tried this and it doesn't make any impact at all... :( Looks exactly the same at the image above